# Generic function for solving n-order polynomial roots in Julia

Tags: julia

All,

I've just been starting to play around with the Julia language and am enjoying it quite a bit. At the end of the 3rd tutorial there's an interesting problem: genericize the quadratic formula such that it solves for the roots of any [n-order polynomial equation](http://forio.com/products/julia-studio/tutorials/beginner/3/).

This struck me as (a) an interesting programming problem and (b) an interesting Julia problem. Has anyone out there solved this one? For reference, here is the Julia code with a couple toy examples. Again, the idea is to make this generic for any n-order polynomial.

Cheers,

Aaron

```
function derivative(f)
    return function(x)
        # pick a small value for h
        h = x == 0 ? sqrt(eps(Float64)) : sqrt(eps(Float64)) * x

        # floating point arithmetic gymnastics
        xph = x + h
        dx = xph - x

        # evaluate f at x + h
        f1 = f(xph)

        # evaluate f at x
        f0 = f(x)

        # divide the difference by h
        return (f1 - f0) / dx
    end
end


function quadratic(f)

    f1 = derivative(f)

    c = f(0.0)

    b = f1(0.0)

    a = f(1.0) - b - c

    return (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4a*c + 0im))/2a, (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4a*c + 0im))/2a
end

quadratic((x) -> x^2 - x - 2)
quadratic((x) -> x^2 + 2)
```

Comment: You should look at the `Polynomial` package and its `roots` function. This finds numeric approximations to the problem for all n. (Algebraic formulas like the quadratic formula are available for n=3,4). As for using a numeric method to find the leading and second coefficients, you will have more accuracy if you use the `PowerSeries` package or `DualNumbers` for the task. The `Calculus` package has something like `derivative` available.

Comment: great, thanks. i'll have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [`PolynomialRoots.jl`](https://github.com/giordano/PolynomialRoots.jl) provides the function `roots()` to find all (real and complex) roots of polynomials of any order.  The only mandatory argument is the array with coefficients of the polynomial in ascending order.

For example, in order to find the roots of

```
6x^5 + 5x^4 + 3x^2 + 2x + 1
```

after loading the package (`using PolynomialRoots`) you can use

```julia
julia> roots([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
5-element Array{Complex{Float64},1}:
           0.294195-0.668367im
 -0.670332+2.77556e-17im
           0.294195+0.668367im
          -0.375695-0.570175im
          -0.375695+0.570175im
```

The package is a Julia implementation of the root-finding algorithm described in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1034

`PolynomialRoots.jl` has also support for arbitrary precision calculation.  This is useful for solving equation that cannot be solved in double precision.  For example

```julia
julia> r = roots([94906268.375, -189812534, 94906265.625]);

julia> (r[1], r[2])
(1.0000000144879793 - 0.0im,1.0000000144879788 + 0.0im)
```

gives the wrong result for the polynomial, instead passing the input array in arbitrary precision forces arbitrary precision calculations that provide the right answer (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance):

```julia
julia> r = roots([BigFloat(94906268.375), BigFloat(-189812534), BigFloat(94906265.625)]);

julia> (Float64(r[1]), Float64(r[2]))
(1.0000000289759583,1.0)
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use this Package, somehow I got two errors: ERROR: LoadError: Declaring __precompile__(false) is not allowed in files that are being precompiled. Any ideas about this? Deeply appreciate~

Comment: Hi, what version of Julia are you using?  The latest version of the package doesn't depend on anything, beside Julia itself, so the error is quite mysterious.  Feel free to open a new ticket at https://github.com/giordano/PolynomialRoots.jl/issues/new that's a better place where to discuss an issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are no algebraic formulae for a general polynomials of degree five and above (infact there cant be [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem)). So theoretically, you could proceed using the same methodology for solutions to cubics and quartics, but even that would be a lot of hard work given very unwieldy formulae for roots of quartics. You could also use a CAS like [SymPy](http://sympy.org/) to find out those formulae.